# Tengo un warning en mi código que no sé quitar

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código:

```
function addTool(label, labelId, editorData, buttons, resultAreaName) {
    var i = 0;
    var result = "";
    var buttonlist = "";
    while (i < buttons.length) {
        newButton = createButton(buttons[i][0], buttons[i][1], buttons[i][2]);
        buttonlist = buttonlist + newButton;
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("tool_list").innerHTML += 
    `<li>
    <p id=${labelId}>${label}</p>
      <textarea id=${editorData[0]} placeholder="${editorData[1]}" rows=${editorData[2]}></textarea>
    <div class="subspaces">
      <div class="buttonlist">${buttonlist}</div>
      <p id=${resultAreaName}>Results will appear here.</p>
    </div>
  </li>`;
}

function createButton(buttonId, buttonName, buttonType) {
    
    switch (buttonType) {
        case "Turnable":
            return `<div class='onoffbutton' id=${buttonId}>${buttonName}</div>`;
        default:
            return `<div class='button' id=${buttonId}>${buttonName}</div>`;
    }
}
```

Y el IDE que estoy usando para buscar los warnings (playcode.io)

ME

MARCA

ERROR

SIN

RAZÓN

justo donde declaro mi función 1 `function addTool` y no sé a qué se debe ni cómo quitarlo. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias por tu atención y espero me puedas ayudar. ¡Ten un lindo día! ✫

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: Eso mismo me pregunto

Comment: Deberías indica cual es el mensaje del 'warning'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La advertencia que genera el IDE es `BugFinder: Function 'addTool' has too many parameters (5). Maximum allowed is 3.`

Según parece esa advertencia está basada en las recomendaciones para escribir código limpio en las que se menciona que: "una función no debería tener más de tres parámetros".

La solución para quitar la advertencia: refactorizar el código para no exceder los tres parámetros.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo puedo refactorizar? No entiendo el término ni sé como hacerlo…